# Ruby on Rails 4 Using chosen and acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-chosen

I want to use the autocomplete with Chosen and ActsAsTaggableOn.

I've successfully implemented ActsAsTaggableOn, but totally confused on how to use Chosen.

Can someone help?

Here is my code.

**Code**

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require turbolinks
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
//= require_tree .
//= require chosen-jquery
```

Application.css

```
*= require chosen
```

pins.js.coffee

```
  $ ->
  # enable chosen js
  $('#pin_tag_list').chosen()
```

Form:

```
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :tag_list, "Tags (separated by commas)" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :tag_list, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
```

Result:

According to the documentation this should work. However, my text field has now broken to a drop down menu and I can't submit tags.

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: I'm trying to make a searchable tagging system with Chosen and ActsAsTaggableOn. I successfully implemented ActsAsTaggableOn, which allows me to separated and submit tags with a commas. I implementing Chosen, which now breaks the original working text field with a broken drop-down menu. When it should look like the following [Link](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Answer (score 0):

From your code sample, it looks like your coffeescript has incorrect indentation. Make sure your jQuery code is nested under your "document ready" function:

```
$ ->
  # enable chosen js
  $('#pin_tag_list').chosen()
```